# Missing method in lightgbm.Booster

Tags: python, lightgbm

It appears that the `trees_to_dataframe` method on a `lightgbm.Booster` objeect is missing. 
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.trees_to_dataframe.

The following code raises an `AttributeError` on the last line.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb

number_of_classes = 5
x = np.random.random((100, 100))
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=number_of_classes, size=100)
data = lgb.Dataset(x, y)

parameters = {
    'objective'             : 'multiclass',
    'num_class'             : number_of_classes,
    'metric'                : ['multi_logloss', ],
}

bst = lgb.train(parameters, data)

assert type(bst) == lgb.Booster
bst.trees_to_dataframe()
```

Comment: They updated recently their docs for the version that has not been released to public yet. See their issues on github, this is not a single missing method/attribute. You have 2 options: either to wait for the next release or build from source.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thank you.  If you post an answer I can mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They updated recently their docs for the version 2.3.2 that has not been released to public yet.

You have 2 options: either to wait for the next release or build from source.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM 
cd LightGBM && mkdir build && cd build    
cmake ..
# cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 .. # build for GPU
make -j12
pip uninstall lightgbm
cd ../python-package/
python setup.py install
```